# How to change the activation function in LSTM cell in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to change the activation function in the LSTM cell from the new 1.0 release of Tensorflow but am having difficulty.

There is tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMcell which the API states should allow for changing functions but it does not seem to be implemented yet for this cell.

Furthermore, tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell, which also should allow for different activation functions doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Do I just need to wait or is there another solution?

Comment: BasicLSTMCell still exists in 1.0 - see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard1/tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell.md

Comment: the above link seems to be broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate both [`tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMcell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) and [`tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell) you can pass the activation function as the `activation` parameter. If you look at the linked documentation, you'll see, for example, that the constructor's signature for `BasicLSTMCell` is

`__init__(num_units, forget_bias=1.0, input_size=None, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.tanh)`